# Size CSS button to HTML border

Tags: html, css, button, border, padding

I have been making a website, and I created a few buttons. Recently I have used css "padding" to size the buttons to be equal in size to each other. What I am wondering is, is there a way that I can size the button to fit with the table border, so it can look nice in any resolution size browser?

[Here is a screenshot of my site so you guys know what you're looking at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtXqL.png)

Comment: Give them `width: 100%`

Comment: @LGSon I tried that and they go past my borders to the right.

Comment: Then you need to post html/CSS so I can see how it looks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `button` a `width:100%` and the `td` a `padding: 0`

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 0;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>Button</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sweet! It worked. Only thing is that then I loose it's height because I had set a padding height. Would I be able to add that back, just without the width?

Comment: Update: I just tried what I mentioned, and that worked to. Thank you so much for your help!